# Serverless Framework: How to solve 'Invalid mapping expression' error while integrating AWS API Gateway and Lambda for asynchronous integration?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

I am trying to use asynchronous integration with AWS API GW and Lambda but it is throwing an error

```
functions:
  getUserInfo:
    handler: functions/common/getABC.handler
    events:
      - http:
          path: common/getABC
          method: get
          async: true
          cors: ${self:custom.cors}
```

Error:

> UPDATE_FAILED: ApiGatewayMethodCommonGetABCGet
> (AWS::ApiGateway::Method) Invalid mapping expression specified:
> Validation Result: warnings : [], errors : [Invalid mapping expression
> specified: true] (Service: AmazonApiGateway; Status Code: 400; Error
> Code: BadRequestException; Request ID:
> ffb54768-30b7-4f91-bb07-1d5df0acea95; Proxy: null)

Can anyone help me with this